# Data Characteristic Changed works on one device and not on an identical second one

Tags: xamarin.forms, bluetoothlescanner

I have a small program to send BluetoothLE data on a Xamarin Forms application.

the bluetoothle device is a Honeywell Dex Adapter.
the handheld devices are Honeywell CT60 running 7.1.1
the port sniffer i use is Device Monitoring Studio

I write to a characteristic and receive data through the DataCharacteristicChange event.

this is how i get the write characteristic

```
WriteCharacteristic = gatt.GetService(DEX_SERVICE_SPP)
                        .GetCharacteristic(DEX_CHARACTERISTIC_DATAWRITE);
```

then i do this

```
gatt.SetCharacteristicNotification(WriteCharacteristic, true)
```

and finally this

BluetoothGattDescriptor descWrite = WriteCharacteristic.GetDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG);

descWrite.SetValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.EnableIndicationValue.ToArray());
                gatt.WriteDescriptor(descWrite);

this is the event that is fired on device #1, but not device #2

```
public override void OnCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)
```

On Device #1, it works, i send 0x05 and get back 0x10 0x30.  The 0x10 0x30 is handled in the DataCharacteristicChanged event.  I see it also in the port sniffer i have.

On Device #2, which is identical to #1 (same OS 7.1.1, upgrade, etc..), the same operation sends the 0x05 but and i get the 0x10 0x30 to the port sniffer but it never gets to the DataCharacteristicEvent in the Device #2.

My question is two-fold.  Does anyone have any idea what could cause this behavior.  What tools could I use to detect difference in configuration between 2 identical devices.

Thanks

Comment: When you switch the connected device, does the characteristic notification re-initialize?You can show some code .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i do not use both devices at same time.  each device is initialized and app executed in its own time.

Comment: You can have a try with traversing the way `GetDescriptor` instead of just processing it once in the code.`foreach (BluetoothGattDescriptor descWrite in WriteCharacteristic.GetDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG))
{
    descWrite.SetValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.EnableIndicationValue.ToArray());
    gatt.WriteDescriptor(descWrite);
}`